# ¿Cómo cambiar el tipo de variable de los datos de una matriz?

Tags: python, numpy

de un programa obtengo los datos de una matriz `a` de la siguiente forma

```
[ 1.,  2.,  3.]
```

los cuales necesito para ubicar posiciones en un arreglo

```
a=np.array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])

b=np.array([ 4,  8, 12, 25, 6])

c = b[a[:]]
```

pero al hacerlo me sale el siguiente error:

```
arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

quiero tenerlos sin el punto  , como los puedo cambiar?

```
[ 1.,  2.,  3.] 
[ 1,  2,  3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres convertir un tipo de numpy array a otro debes usar la función [`astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

```
c = b[a[:].astype(int)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar una sencilla "comprensión de listas", para convertir todos los valores en enteros, de la siguiente forma:

```
lista_int = [int(e) for e in [ 1.,  2.,  3.]]
```

Basicamente, iteramos por cada elemento `e` de la lista original y convertimos cada uno en un valor entero `int(e)`